# Django: Auto Populate CharField using Urllib2

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, urllib2

I am working on a Djnago project and was wondering if I could use information i parsed using Urllib2 to auto-populate a feilds for a large amount of data quickly. Here is my models

```
from django.db import models

class Stocks(models.Model):
    Ticker = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Exchange = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Industry = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    About = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Stocks"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Ticker
```

So far I have done this using a data from a CSV to populate the the fields, "Ticker," "Name," and "Exchange" like so (uisng "python manage.py shell"):

```
import csv
from stocks.models import Stocks
fields = ["Ticker", "Name", "Exchange"]
for row in csv.reader(open('NASDAQ.csv', 'rU'), dialect='excel'):
    Stocks.objects.create(**dict(zip(fields, row)))
```

I was wondering if I could auto-populate the "Industry" field the same way pulling data from urllib2. Here is my relevany urllib2 code:

```
indusCode = urllib2.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/in?s="+t).read()
industry = indusCode.split('<b>Industry: ')[1].split('</b>')[0]
industry = industry.replace("&amp;", "&")
```

Anyone know if I can use the data pulled from urllib2 to populate the "Industry" field? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

```
import csv
from stocks.models import Stocks
fields = ["Ticker", "Name", "Exchange"]
for row in csv.reader(open('NASDAQ.csv', 'rU'), dialect='excel'):
    row_dict = dict(zip(fields, row))
    indusCode = urllib2.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/in?s=" + row_dict['Ticker']).read()
    industry = indusCode.split('<b>Industry: ')[1].split('</b>')[0]
    industry = industry.replace("&amp;", "&") 
    row_dict['Industry'] = industry
    Stocks.objects.create(**row_dict)
```

Haven't tested.  But I believe something similar to that should work.

Comment: Thank you, this worked like a charm. However, when I run it, the code creates a new ticker and add the Industry name to the new ticker, instead of adding it to the existing Ticker that I created before. Any way to get around this?

Comment: Well, you're calling create.  If the ticker already exists as a `Stocks` object then you first need to get that object then just update the values.  Something like `if Stocks.objects.filter(Ticker=row_dict['Ticker']).exists():` then you create a reference object and just assign the values that way.  If that `if` fails then you can put all the previously posted code inside the `else:` block.  Bonus, for already existing `Stock` objects you wouldn't need to update the industry.

Comment: Ok, I've made some edits to my code, however nothing seems to be happening when I run it. You can see my code [here](http://pastebin.com/GkVFaDgG)

Comment: This should have been posted as another question.  However you have to fetch the object before you can make changes to it.  [Example pastebin](http://pastebin.com/biwi1pd2)